# ¿como sera al contrario?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Si esta Consulta lee el MDF para saber la version del archivo MDF, ¿cual me indica que acepta mi base de datos?

DBCC CHECKPRIMARYFILE('C:\DATA\basedata_person.mdf',2)